# Quartz is not participating in EJB transactions (in CMT mode)

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, quartz-scheduler, jta

I integrated Quartz2.2.2 with my Java EE application which is running in Weblogic 12.1.2. I want to handle all JTA transactions with my container (Weblogic). 
But when an exception is occurred everything is rollbacked except for quartz transactions, I think the problem goes back to `quartz.properties` here is my config file:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.weblogic.WebLogicOracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = quartz
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource = quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.quartz.jndiURL = java.weblogic.datasources.quartz
```

I set both managed transactions' datasource and nonManaged one to the same datasource and it seems to be wrong! But I couldn't understand why I should set `nonManagedTXDataSource`  and this field is mandatory!
In documentation of quartz web site it is suggested that:

> JobStoreCMT requires a (second) datasource that contains connections
>   that will not be part of container-managed transactions. The value of
>   this property must be the name of one the DataSources defined in the
>   configuration properties file. This datasource must contain non-CMT
>   connections, or in other words, connections for which it is legal for
>   Quartz to directly call commit() and rollback() on.

Why I need such a datasource when I want all my transactons to be managed by the container!

Code example:

```
@Stateless
public class MyServiceHandlerBean {

    @EJB
    MyObjectManager objManager;

    @EJB
    MyScheduler scheduler;

    public void addObj() throws MyException {
    MyObject obj = new MyObject("fname","lastname");
    objManager.save(obj);
    scheduler.addJobForObj(obj);
    }
}
```

and `MyScheduler` class that works with quartz:

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class MyScheduler {

    private Scheduler scheduler = null;

    public MyScheduler() throws SchedulerException {
        scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
    }

    public void addJobForObj(MyObject obj) throws MyException {
        JobBuilder jobBuilder = newJob(BaseJob.class).withIdentity(obj.getId());
        JobDetail job = jobBuilder.build();

    try {
        // Does something to create triggers
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, triggers, false);
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
           throw new MyException("Something");
        } catch (MyException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
 }
```

and here is `MyException` class code:

```
@ApplicationException(rollback=true)
public class MyException extends Exception{

}
```

The problem is when I call `MyServiceHandlerBean` method (`addObj`) when save operation of `MyObjectManager` fails container rolls transaction back but the job is added to the Database of quartz scheduler.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: sample code is added

Comment: Try to print out the transaction id that Quartz is using

Comment: isn't there anything that is wrong in my config file? should I use for both managed and non-managed transaction data sources same data source name?

Comment: And there is not so easy to print out transaction ID because it is handled by container and I just access to seRollbackOnly and getRollBackOnly

Comment: You can retrieve transaction id with @Resource TransactionSynchronizationRegistry txReg;

Comment: I uesed, but txReg is null always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while I found that it was my mistake! Maybe this should be a comment but I think it can be more useful if I post it as an answer. My mistake was in the Weblogic data-source configuration. I should have enabled **Support Global Transaction** in the data-source transaction configuration.